# Alternative to nth-child approach in automatic css selector generation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web-scraping

I am facing a problem while making a logic for automatic generation of CSS path of an element in a web page.

Use-Case: When a user clicks on any element on a web page, a CSS selector is generated automatically using CSS selector concepts like id-name, class-name, tag-name, and nth-child.

For ex: Lets say I click on a price element on an e-commerce product description page, what I will get is something like `body > ul:nth-child(27) > li:nth-child(1)`. The biggest BANE here is `nth-child(1)`, because for this page the price is the 1st child, but for other pages it could be 4th or 5th or 23rd child. Moreover, the bigger problem is that HTML of price element is

```
<html>
    ....
    <body>
          <div>ABC</div>
          <div>DEF
               <span>GHI</span>
               <ul>
                   <li> PRICE: $32.23 </div>
                   <li> WEIGHT: 100 lbs </div>  
               </ul>
          </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

without any classname or id-name. My current selector generation logic generates a lot of combinations of selectors but selects the selector which is most unique.

Please help me!

Comment: Is setting an id for the price tag element an option? You could dinamically add an id for them like `#price-tag21`, `#price-tag22`, etc.

Comment: I would ask a more fundemental question: Why are you generating selectors? The usual approach is that your selectors are fixed and you modify some attribute in the markup (`class` or `id` usually) to apply the desired style.

Comment: @BrunoHenrique : Thanks for your answer. Yes dynamically adding id is an option but if I mark price as #price-tag21 on base page then it is not necessary that #price-tag21 is the same element that i need on other pages.

Comment: @DarkFalcon: I am generating selectors to record the location of a web element in a product description page so that I can programmatically go to that location afterwards but the ugly truth is that each page is little different from each other. So, I am looking for ideas for this problem.

Comment: How would you know that a certain element in a certain page is exactly the same element in another page? It seems that even checking for the "most unique" selector would give produce quite fragile results.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to use numerically named selectors in your case. Maybe adding a specific data from the product as a selecotr name like `.pencil-id-2312` solve your problem, but it'd a very ugly solution.

Comment: If you're pulling all this data from a database, then it would be best to use `id`'s based on the primary keys in the database.

Comment: @Haroldo_OK: I have changed the format of the HTML in the question above slightly. So, the part of the LHS of numerical figure remains constant. Here, that part is "PRICE:" & "WEIGHT". With the help of presence of "PRICE:" & "WEIGHT:", I can know the price & weight but the CSS selector will fail to locate them accurately if their position in the list gets changed.

Comment: @BrunoHenrique: If I add data manually in one page, how will other pages will get that manual tagging. I think this is prone to breaking.

Comment: @divinecomedian: Thanks for your solution but no database in involved here. Just the web page and its DOM.

Comment: You shouldn't add data manually. Instead, for the solution I proposed, you should do a js function to read the data from your product, get some id or name that is unique for the product, and add dinamically the selector with this unique data as key, so the product would have the same selector in every page.

Comment: @BrunoHenrique: I got it now. I can give approach a try. What I get from this is that: If I click on this PRICE: $23.32, then a JS function will read the textContent inside <li> element and make this text as a id of this <li> element. But the next question is that how to uniquely generate id for this <li> element? Each product with have different price.

Comment: That depends on a unique data from each <li> element. You can use something like a name, product id, whichever product data on textContent that is unique for this element.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <span class='product'>Cheese</span>
           <ul class='product-details' >
               <li class='price' id='Cheese-price'> PRICE: $32.23 </li>
               <li class='weight' id='Cheese-weight'> WEIGHT: 100 lbs </li>  
           </ul>
 <span class='product'>Apple</span>
           <ul class='product-details' >
               <li class='price' id='Apple-price'> PRICE: $2.23 </li>
               <li class='weight' id='Apple-weight'> WEIGHT: 1 lbs </li>  
           </ul>
```

My concept is that you add classes to classify and make unique ids based on product name and `-price` or `-weight` suffixes, ex.: `Cheese-price`. Then you might use some jquery functions that identify elements by class or by end of attribute name: `-price`

> because for this page the price is the 1st child, but for other pages it could be 4th or 5th or 23rd child.
>
> If I click on this PRICE: $23.32, then a JS function will read the textContent inside `li` element
>
> I click on a price element on an e-commerce product description page
>
> ...but no database in involved here. Just the web page and its DOM

Do you generate css selectors on server side or only thru `js function` upon a user click? If the later, then you are in the wrong sphere.

### Update

Since you try to add css selectors on client side (after receiving HTML page), my suggestion to you is to grab the hole page, save it locally and process it with [regex](http://scraping.pro/regex-expressions/) based on words `PRICE` and `WEIGHT`. ex.: `/PRICE:\s+\$([\.\d]+)/g`

See [working demo](https://regex101.com/r/nC0pN3/1).

Comment: @Ken2015, see my update and would you check my answer up?